# How do I hyperlink to a specific slide of a .ppt file?

Tags: hyperlink, powerpoint

I want to link to a specific slide in an online PowerPoint file, (e.g.  `http://www.example.com/hello.ppt`) but what I want is that when people click on my link, it goes straight to the nth slide.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16):

Link to

http://www.whatever.com/hello.ppt**#4**

for slide 4 to be opened initially.

Take a look at this site:
http://www.tinyempire.com/shortnotes/files/specific_slide_in_ppt.htm

Comment: Does this still work?  I can't get this to work with OneDrive.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you want a link to the nth slide within the same file (to automate the 'Edit Hyperlink' > 'Place in This Document' action) then omit the filename and only set it to "#n".

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. all you have to do is add #n after .ppt.

For example, http://www.whatever.com/hello.ppt#4  will take you straight to the 4th slide.

Answer (score 0):

The following method applies to any online version of PowerPoint (e.g. Office 365).

1. Open the powerpoint file in your browser (the link could look like this: http://YourCompany.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/SiteName/...)
2. In the thumbnails list (on the left), right-click on the slide you want to refer to and choose "link to this slide" (free translation, my version is in Dutch "Koppeling naar deze dia")
3. In the pop-up screen, you can choose to share a read-only or an editable version