# iOS : jump to a specific slide in ppt

Tags: ios, uiwebview, powerpoint

I've one ppt file locally that I'm opening with `UIWebView` with below code, file having 10 slides, now with the requirement, I want to jump to a specific slide, something like if I want to directly jump to slide#3 then how to do it with this code?

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"ppt"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

//open ppt into UIWebView like,
[self loadDocument:@"newone" inView:self.myWebview];
```

I searched here, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229/how-do-i-hyperlink-to-a-specific-slide-of-a-ppt-file), they are doing

> Link to http://www.whatever.com/hello.ppt#4 for slide 4 to be opened initially.

but my ppt file is saved into document directory (locally) within my app.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the offset of `UIWebview` ScrollView.

```
[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(widht, height) animated:YES];
```

Find height of one slide in current zoom scale. Multiply it with four as forth page to open initially. and put in above code with point CGPointMake(0, heightYouCalculated)